# Email validation in Java without using regular expression

Tags: java, email-validation

I understand that validating email with **Regex** would have just been a matter of 3-4 lines of code. However, I'm looking to validate email **`without using`** **`Regex.`** To an extent, the code successfully passes almost all the validations, however, still unable to figure out - how special characters can be avoided being the first & last character of the email address.

**List of specialChars =** `{'!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '/', '~', '[', ']'} ;`

**What I am looking at is:**

> If the username section (**`abc.xyz`**@gmail.com) starts or ends with
>   any of the special characters, it should trigger an **"Invalid email
>   address" error.** The same goes with domain section as well.

**For eg...** the following list of **email-IDs** should print an **"Invalid email ID"** **`error message`**

> **`#abc.xyz@gmail.com`**
>
> **`abc.xyz&@gmail.com`**
>
> **`abc.xyz&@!gmail.com`**
>
> **`abc.xyz&@gmail.com!`**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Email_Validation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // User-input code
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your email address");
        String email = scan.next();

        // Code to check if email ends with '.' (period sign) 
        boolean checkEndDot  = false;
        checkEndDot = email.endsWith(".");

        // Code to find out last index of '@' sign
        int indexOfAt = email.indexOf('@');
        int lastIndexOfAt = email.lastIndexOf('.');


        //Code to check occurence of @ in the email address  
        int countOfAt = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {
            if(email.charAt(i)=='@')
                countOfAt++; }


        // Code to check occurence of [period sign i..e, "."] after @ 
        String buffering = email.substring(email.indexOf('@')+1, email.length());
        int len = buffering.length();

        int countOfDotAfterAt = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
            if(buffering.charAt(i)=='.')
                countOfDotAfterAt++; }


// Code to print userName & domainName
            String userName = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@'));
            String domainName = email.substring(email.indexOf('@')+1, email.length());

                System.out.println("\n");   

               if ((countOfAt==1) && (userName.endsWith(".")==false)  && (countOfDotAfterAt ==1) &&   
                  ((indexOfAt+3) <= (lastIndexOfAt) && !checkEndDot)) {

                   System.out.println("\"Valid email address\"");}

               else {       
                        System.out.println("\n\"Invalid email address\""); }


                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("User name: " +userName+ "\n" + "Domain name: " +domainName);


    }
}
```

**How do I get this resolved ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
public class EmailMe {
  private static Set<Character> bad = new HashSet<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] specialChars = new char[] {'!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '/', '~', '[', ']'} ;
    for (char c : specialChars) {
      bad.add(c);
    }
    check("#abc.xyz@gmail.com");
    check("abc.xyz&@gmail.com");
    check("abc.xyz&@!gmail.com");
    check("abc.xyz&@gmail.com!");
  }

  public static void check(String email) {
    String name = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@'));
    String domain = email.substring(email.indexOf('@')+1, email.length());
//    String[] split = email.split("@");
    checkAgain(name);
    checkAgain(domain);
  }


  public static void checkAgain(String part) {
    if (bad.contains(part.charAt(0))) System.out.println("bad start:"+part);
    if (bad.contains(part.charAt(part.length()-1))) System.out.println("bad end:"+part);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does give you the output, but not the way I would have wanted. So, I'm a bit skeptical about using it because as far as possible I'm looking for a solution that avoids **even** the **shadow of Regex**, in **`some or the other way.`**  Had it been using Regex, the solution would have been pretty simple & lastly, it would have not found the space here.

Comment: Your own example code finds the '@' char and uses that index to get the part after the @ char. Just replace the email.split() with that code and get the parts before and after. Then there is no "hint of regex".

Comment: **`Thanks mate...`**  **I had to make few changes in your code to fit into the existing code, but at last, it worked like a charm.. !!!**

Answer (score 1):

So, take a look at the String API.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Specifically, you've got String.length(), and String.charAt().  So you can get the first and last characters from the String very, very easily.  You do this in your code at one point already; assuming you've got it.

You could run through a long if statement here;

```
char first = email.charAt(0);
if (first == '!' || first == '#' || <more here>) { 
    return false;
}
```

But that could be a headache.  Another way to do this would be to use a Set, which is more efficient if you need to check this many times.  (Lookup into a HashSet is generally pretty quick.)  You'd create the set once, then be able to use it many times with Set.contains(first), for example.

Comment: But, what I'm looking at is the special characters should not be either the first OR last character. **(applies to both - username as well domain section)** How do I implement the same using HashSet ?

Comment: For also doing the last character, do it a second time with email.charAt(email.size() - 1).

Comment: For the Set, create a HashSet, put in all of the special characters, and instead of a large "if" statement, you can just check hashSet.contains(firstCharacter) and hashSet.contains(lastCharacter).

Comment: But the problem here is, the **email address** is coming as a `User-input` and not as part of the Collections framework. So, how is it possible to check with **hash.contains()** `method` ?

Comment: I'm **still naive** with **regards to Collections framework.**  **`If you could explain with the help of some code, it would be easy to co-relate things & thereby help in understanding things smoothly.`**

Answer (score 1):

I use [EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html) from the Apache Commons library.
An example above,

```
String email = "anEmailAddress@domain.com";
EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
if (!validator.isValid(email)) {
   // The email is not valid.
}
```

or

```
if (!EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("anEmailAddress@domain.com")) {
   // The email is not valid.
}
```

If you are using maven then you can use [this dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.4.0),

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, I believe it satisfies your email validation.

Apache common lang maven [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4).

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Java **email** validation utility code.

```
public class EmailValidationUtility {


    private static final String[] SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_FOR_USERNAME = new String[] {
                "..", "__", ",", "/", "<", ">", "?", ";", ":", "\"", "\"",
                "{", "}", "[", "]", "|", "\\", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^",
                "&", "*", "(", ")", "+", "=", "~", "`" };

    private static final char[] SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_WITH_NUMBERS = new char[] {
                '.', ',', '/', '<', '>', '?', ';', ':', '\'', '\"', '{',
                '}', '[', ']', '|', '\\', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&',
                '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '~', '`', '1', '2', '3',
                '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };

    /**
     * Method to validate the input email is valid or not.
     *
     * @param email the email
     * @return true, if is email valid
     */
    public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        String[] emailChunks = StringUtils
                        .splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(email,
                                        "@");

        if (emailChunks.length != 2 || isEmailUserNameInvalid(emailChunks[0])
                        || StringUtils.isBlank(emailChunks[1])) {
            return false;
        }

        String[] domainNames = StringUtils
                        .splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(emailChunks[1],
                                        ".");
        if (domainNames.length < 2) {
            return false;
        }

        int topLevelDomainNameIndex = domainNames.length - 1;
        if (isTopLevelDomainNameInvalid(domainNames[topLevelDomainNameIndex])) {
            return false;
        }

        domainNames = ArrayUtils.remove(domainNames, topLevelDomainNameIndex);

        return (isDomainNameValid(domainNames));
    }



    private static boolean isEmailUserNameInvalid(String emailUserName) {
        return (StringUtils.isBlank(emailUserName) || StringUtils.containsAny(
                        emailUserName, SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_FOR_USERNAME));
    }


    private static boolean isTopLevelDomainNameInvalid(String topLevelDomain) {
        return (StringUtils.isBlank(topLevelDomain) || StringUtils.containsAny(
                        topLevelDomain, SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_WITH_NUMBERS));
    }
    
    private static boolean isDomainNameValid(String[] domainNames) {
        for (String domainName : domainNames) {
            if ((StringUtils.isBlank(domainName) || StringUtils.containsAny(
                            domainName, SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_WITH_NUMBERS))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```